# SQL Database Design for Test Data

Tags: sql, database, sql-server-2008, testing

So, I am trying to learn how to set up good, and usable databases. I have ran into a problem involving storing large amounts of data correctly. The database I am using is MSSQL 2008. For example:

We test about 50,000 devices a week. Each one of these devices have a lot of data associated with them. Overall, we are just looking at the summary of data calculated from the raw data. The summary is easy to handle, its just the raw data I'm trying to enter into a database for future use in case someone wants more details.

For the summary, I have a database full of tables for each set of 50,000 devices. But, each device there is data similar to this:

```
("DevID") I,V,P I,V,P I,V,P ...
("DevID") WL,P WL,P WL,P ...
```

Totaling to 126 (~882 chars) data points for the first line and 12000 (~102,000 chars) data points for the second line. What would be the best way to store this information? Create a table for each and every device (this seems unruly)? Is there a data type that can handle this much info? I am just not sure.

Thanks!

EDIT: Updated ~char count and second line data points.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just normalize everything into one table

```
CREATE TABLE device
(  id         BIGINT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
,  DevID      INT
,  DataPoint  VARCHAR
,  INDEX(DevID))
```

Psudocode obviously, since I don't know your exact requirements.

Comment: I was thinking varchar but I have well over 54000 chars for the second line of data. I guess varchar can only hold 8000.

Comment: Each char would be on a new record.  So for the first example, there would be three rows for I, three for V and and three for P.

Comment: OH I see! Hmm, interesting... Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Does this data represent a series of readings over time? Time-series data tends to be highly repetetive. So a common strategy is to compress it in ways that avoid storing every single value. For example use [run-length encoding](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Run-LengthEncoding.html), or associate time intervals with each value instead of single points.

Comment: They are not readings over time. They are readings over a current range. i.e. 1mA, 2mA, 3mA. This would work if there where similar values, but they are all different.